# Building cordova-plugin-xapkreader with cordova-android 6.4.0

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I've inherited a cordova project that uses cordova-plugin-xapkreader, which appears to be the standard plugin for accessing expansion (aka OBB) files. I'm encountering an issue with it that I would expect to affect other cordova plugins. I get the following errors when running `cordova build android`:

```
Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:downloader_library' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'debugCompile' in project ':com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:downloader_library' is deprecated. Use 'debugImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'releaseCompile' in project ':com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:downloader_library' is deprecated. Use 'releaseImplementation' instead.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:library' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:library.
     Required by:
         project : > project :com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:downloader_library
      > Project :com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:downloader_library declares a dependency from configuration 'debugCompile' to configuration 'debug' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader:library.
```

This has been reported as a bug on the plugin's forum by someone else, but the workaround doesn't reliable work:

https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/issues/116

The issue appears to be that gradle expects you to now use `implementation` rather than `compile`, `debugCompile` etc. The gradle file for the plugin is generated by cordova, based on a template inside cordova-android. The suggested workaround is to modify the template (or the generated gradle files) in a script run from a cordova hook. Unfortunately for some reason, the hooks don't appear to work reliably - sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. This feels like it may be due to a race condition caused by the hooks running asynchronously with the rest of the build process - so sometimes the gradle build has started before the gradle files can be modified.

Does any have any ideas how to properly fix this? Does anyone know why this isn't a more wide-spread issue that the cordova-android project hasn't fixed by modifying their template? Is this something I can fix by downgrading some part of the build process?

I'm pretty new to Cordova, so it's all quite baffling and any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately for some reason, the hooks don't appear to work reliably
>   - sometimes they do, sometimes they don't. This feels like it may be due to a race condition caused by the hooks running asynchronously
>   with the rest of the build process - so sometimes the gradle build has
>   started before the gradle files can be modified.

I think this can be fixed by making the hook return a promise, this way you can ensure the rest of the build won't run in parallel. I posted the code I'm using on the github issue.

The revelant code is the following:
 - create a promise at the beginning of the hook:
`const deferral = context.requireCordovaModule('q').defer();`
 - return the promise at the end of the hook:
`return deferral.promise;`
 - resolve the promise once the work is finished (the file is written):
`deferral.resolve();`